# 2022 calendar in C determine starting day

Tags: c

I need to write a program in C that it prints a month chosen by the user from the year 2022.

If the user enter January (has 31 days) and the user enter to print 20 days, then should be printed from 1st January untill 20 January.

Same for every month.

I have this pice of code but I'm not happy with it and I googled everything.

```
void print_month(char *mo, int number_day_userInput){
     
       int i,j; // as counters
       int week = 7; // as 7 days in a week
       int day=1;
       int day_of_the_week=1;


       printf("M\tT\tW\tT\tF\tS\tS");
       //January
       if(strcmp(mo, "January")== 0){
         for(i=0;i<=5;i++){ // this 5 is as 5 weeks in January
           printf("\n");
           for(j=1;j<=week;j++){
             if(day_of_the_week>=6){ // 1st day start printing
             printf("%i",day);
             day++;
             if(day > number_day_userInput){
               break;
          }
        }
          day_of_the_week++;
          printf("\t");
      }
    }
    printf("\n\nJanuary has 31 days");

  }
```

I can't figure it out, how to determine for each month where to start printing the first day. For example,  January 1st starts  on a Saturday, the 6th day. February starts on 2nd day. Also, I don't know how to determine how many weeks are in a month. Could you please share some ideas ? Not necessarily in C, but an advice will be welcomed. Thank you

Comment: since you know the starting day of January, which is day 6 (assuming indices 0 - 6 inclusive) you can ```+=``` the amount of days in each month and ```%``` with value ```7```. Have a int array of size 12. ```int days[12] = {31, 28, 31, ...}``` then for each month choose the corresponding value. Since January starts with day 6, to find what day March starts at... ```int marchStartDate = (6 + days[0] + days[1]) % 7``` which is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I started with Sunday as day 0 (Gregorian calendar). It should print out correctly based on the month given. Core concept here is just using the modulus operator `%` to find remainders, and basic for-loop stuff :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int daysOfMonth[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
static int start = 6;

void print_month(char *mo, int number_day_userInput)
{
  int j = 0;
  if(strcmp(mo, "February") == 0) { j = 1; }
  else if(strcmp(mo, "March") == 0) { j = 2; }
  else if(strcmp(mo, "April") == 0) { j = 3; } // and so on...

  for(int i = 0; i < j; ++i)
  {
    start += daysOfMonth[i];
  }
  int startDay = start % 7;

  printf("S\tM\tT\tW\tT\tF\tS\n");
  for(int tab = 0; tab < startDay; ++tab)
  {
    printf("\t");
  }
  for(int day = 1; day <= number_day_userInput; ++day)
  {
    printf("%d\t", day);
    if(++startDay % 7 == 0)
    {
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
  print_month("March", 20);
}
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT of print_month("January", 31):

```
S   M   T   W   T   F   S
                        1
2   3   4   5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20  21  22
23  24  25  26  27  28  29
30  31
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try now to find out how many Saturdays or Sundays or a given day by the user , a specific month have when I will come back home. Just wanted to say Thank you